# 400 Bad Request when using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, http

I am sending a Http POST request to my RESTful API build with Spring Boot and get the "400 Bad Request" response.

My POST request is made with Postman, send to

```
http://localhost:8080/executebash
```

with the body

```
{
    "filename": "blaba"
}
```

I want to pass the `filename` variable to my Java Method.
My RESTful api is build in Java with Spring Boot

```
@RestController
public class PrapiController {

    private Process process;
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/executebash", produces ="application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String executeBashScript(@RequestParam String filename) {
        //...
    }
}
```

I tried with and with out produces in the `@RequestMapping` annotation.
I have no idea where the error comes from, maybe you can help me.

Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `@RequestBody` to accept data in request body. As shown in below example:

```
@RestController
public class PrapiController {

    private Process process;
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/executebash", consumes="application/json", produces ="application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String executeBashScript(@RequestBody Map<String, String> input) {
        String filename = input.get("filename");

        return "{}";
    }
}
```

Comment: I implemented this, but now I get the response: 415 Unsupported Media Type. What do I need to change/add?

Comment: Need to add ```consumes="application/json"``` in RequestMapping. Or you can use ```@PostMapping("/executebash")``` annotation. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I had a similar problem. But it's due to the mismatch of the enum value in the request json.

Answer (score 3):

With [`@RequestParam`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) annotation you have to use param in request URL instead of body with JSON:

```
http://localhost:8080/executebash?filename=blaba
```

If you want use your JSON, you have to use [`@RequestBody`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html) with data transfer object or `Map<String, String>` like @pcsutar said.